# How to add a new row to a Twitter Bootstrap Datatable using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add a new row to the twitter bootstrap datatable using JQuery so my first approach was using this:

```
$("#searchResultsTableTBody").append(newRow);
```

A lot of work and html inside the javascript and the new row was added, but then if I try to use the sort, expand all, etc from the datatable, it loses the data I added. I think I need to add the new line by calling some function from datatable like I saw on this link:

[Create a new row in bootstrap data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231808/create-a-new-row-in-bootstrap-data-table)

But I don't know how to identify the fields I need to pass as parameter.
What is the best way to insert a new line to the bootstrap datatable?

I'm using thymeleaf and grails as well.

--
Based on the link provided:

https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()

I tried to do this:

```
var searchResult = {workItemId:12345, workItemTypeCode:"Doe", workItemTypeDescription:"test1", itemNumber:"12", workItemDescription:"John", organizationLabel:"Doe", organizationHierarchy:"Doe Here", academicYearLabel:"blue", expanded:false, editing:false, assignmentCount:0};

var t = $('#searchResultsTable').DataTable();
t.row.add(searchResult).draw();
```

On my html this is what I have on my datatable for the first column:

```
<tbody id="searchResultsTableTBody">
  <th:block th:each="searchResult : ${searchResults}">
  <th:block th:if="${!(searchResult.editing)}">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="parent_1" 
        th:id="|parent_${searchResult.workItemId}|"
        th:attr="data-target='#child_'+${searchResult.workItemId}+''"
        th:checked="${searchResult.expanded}"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#child_1">
      </input>
      <label for="parent_1"                                                    
        th:for="|parent_${searchResult.workItemId}|">
      </label>
    </td>
```

When I run the js code I get an alert with this message:

> DataTables warning: table id=searchResultsTable - Requested unknown
>   parameter '0' for row 9, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

And based on this link: http://datatables.net/tn/4 the reason for that is that the column 0 (the one I copied) is trying to access an information that it couldn't find.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the way I'm setting the information.

That's the generated HTML:

```
<table id="searchResultsTable" width="100%" class="table parent-table-striped table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th> <!-- Expand/collapse checkbox -->
      <th></th> <!-- Edit/Delete buttons -->
      <th style="display: none;">Child Grouping</th>
      <th>Non-Instructional Workload Item</th>
      <th style="display: none;">Child row count</th>
      <th>Academic Year</th>
      <th>Work Item</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Org Level</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="searchResultsTableTBody">


    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent_4087" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#child_4087">
        </input>
        <label for="parent_4087">
        </label>
      </td>
      <td><a href="/nonInstructionalWorkload/editWorkItem?workItemId=4087"><span class="fa fa-pencil"> </span></a>
        <button id="btnDelete" value="delete" type="button" class="btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-object-id="4087" data-object-name="ATHL-1" data-target="#deleteNonInstructionalModal">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
      <!-- Child Rows Grouping value -->
      <td style="display: none;">parent_4087</td>
      <td>ATHL-1</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td>2017/18</td>
      <td>Athletics</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Academic Affairs Admin.">AADM</a></td>
    </tr>



    <!-- Show Edit Form -->

    <!-- End Show Edit Form -->

    <!--  Start Assignment Detail  -->
    <tr id="child_4087" class="collapse">
      <!-- expand / collapse checkbox -->
      <td></td>
      <!-- edit/delete buttons -->
      <td></td>
      <!-- parent/child grouping -->
      <td style="display: none;">parent_4087</td>
      <td style="display: none;">ATHL-1</td>
      <td style="display: none;">0</td>
      <td style="display: none;">2017/18</td>
      <td style="display: none;">Athletics</td>
      <td style="display: none;">1</td>                                               
      <td style="display: none;">AADM</td>
      <td colspan="7">
        <div>
          <span>
            <table>

              <tr>
                <td><a href="/nonInstructionalWorkload/addAssignment?workItemId=4087"> <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"> </span>
                  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="10"><a href="/nonInstructionalWorkload/addAssignment?workItemId=4087"> Add Assignment </a></td>
              </tr>

              <!-- Show Add Form -->

              <!-- End Show Add Form -->
              <!--  OFFLINE Add Form -->

            </table>
          </span>
          <table id="subSearchResultsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <!-- Add and Edit Buttons -->
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Faculty Name</th>
                <th>Load Type</th>
                <th>Load Value</th>
                <th>Section Equivalent</th>
                <th>Cost Centre</th>
                <th>Assign Start Date</th>
                <th>Assign End Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Notes</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>


              <!--  OFFLINE Edit Form -->

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

And that's how it look like:
[image]

I'm not sure if I got it right. On my parameters to add the new row, I'm passing the parameters used by thymeleaf to populate each column. The edit and delete button for instace, they use the workItemId, that I'm passing as a parameter to the datatable.

Comment: DataTables uses internally saved data to sort the table (and a re-draw cause). This [documentation page](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) is what you need to read.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - It helped a lot! Thank you. I'm now having another problem. I just updated my question in case you can help.

Comment: Do you at least have the same column count in your HTML than in your json?... I think that's what this error is about. Can you show the "produced" HTML (before the row addition)? What you posted looks like Angular or I don't know what similar, and I'm not used to it. Also show the `<thead>` content.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Just added more information with the whole html source for the table and a screenshot as well.

Comment: I'm unsure... But I think that your nested table is causing the issue. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33765560/2159528) which seems related.